# Is this a correct usage of participial phrase?

Tags: participle-phrases

Is this sentence correct?

> I managed a website **being used by** thousands of people on a daily basis

Comment: It looks fine to me. Did you have a particular concern with it?

Comment: @Jason Bassford I am a bit unfamiliar with the use of participial phrase so just wanted to get it confirmed.

Comment: It's fine but not necessary: I managed a website used by thousands of people.

Answer (score 1):

'Being used' sounds slightly odd in this context, as does 'used by thousands of people on a daily basis'.  This sounds like something you would say in a resumé. If so, I would keep it simple and just say:

> I managed a website used by thousands of people daily.

If you want to retain the idea of 'being used', and you managed this work in the past, replace 'being used' with 'was used'. It does not sound as odd.

If you want to retain the idea of being used, and you are still managing this work, replace 'being used' with 'is used'. Generally, in a resumé, what you are currently doing should take precedence over what you have done.

Comment: Both _was_ and _is_ require a "that" before them in this context.